# How to ignore an unknown subclass with single collection inheritance in Mongoid?

Tags: mongoid, mongoid4

The default inheritance method for Mongoid is creating a single collection for all subclasses. For instance:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
end

class Admin < User
end

class Guest < User
end
```

Internally, Mongoid adds a `_type` field to each document with the class name, which is used to automatically map each instance to the right class.

The problem is, if I have a document in this collection with an unknown `_type` value, I get an exception:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant UnknownClass
```

This can happen if you create a new subclass of `User`, in the example above, and a migration that creates a new instance of this new subclass. Until you restart your servers, every query to this collection (like `User.all.to_a`). Is there a safe way to avoid this error?

The only solution I came up is rescuing `NameError` exception and querying by all known subclasses:

```
class User
  def self.some_query(params)
    self.where(params).to_a
  rescue NameError => e
    Rails.logger.error "Unknown subclass: #{e.message}"

    subtypes = self.descendants.map(&:to_s)
    self.where(params.merge(:_type.in => subtypes)).to_a
  end
end
```